# How import content data to Google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to import content data by downloading a csv file. To do this, create a special parameter with Hit scope. After that, in the "data import" tab, I create a new group where the key is the page, and the imported data is my user parameter. Successfully upload a csv file. In it, pagePath is part of the url, and demension is the author.
I use this example
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3271771?hl=en
It seems that I’m doing everything according to the official certificate, but even after 48 hours the data are not loaded into a special report. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Show your import data setup and an example of your URL, please.

Comment: @MichelePisani my url like example.com/example1/example2/
so for cvs i use /example1/example2/    [import data setup](https://sun3-10.userapi.com/OCBROqBk3aTqNFbF4tJACQA5Dxt7aXbz17EF_A/_P9-bRTEt18.jpg)